# How to use value from 'join' clause in 'where' clause?

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework2

There is join, and I need to include value from it in 'where'. Is there any way to do this? In other words, I want to apply 'where' clause only to that values, which being joined. I'm really got confused with it, and may be this task can be solved more easily.

```
$this->table = "CoolTable";
$sql = new Sql($this->getAdapter());
    $select = $sql->select()
        ->columns(array(/*some expressions...*/))
        ->from($this->table)
        ->join(
            array('ct' => 'CoolTable'),
            new Expression('
                ct.a = CoolTable.a AND
                ct.b = CoolTable.b
            '),
            array()
        )
        /*another joins...*/
        ->where(array(
            'CoolTable.a' => $someExternalVar,
            'CoolTable.b = ?' => '$ct.a',
        ))
```

What about my tries:

1. `'CoolTable.b = ?' => '$ct.a'`
2. `'CoolTable.b' => 'ct.a'`
3. `'CoolTable.b' => new Expression('ct.a')` `/*it's a really pity, yes*/`
4. `new Predicate\PredicateSet(
                   array(
                       new Operator(
                           'CoolTable.b',
                           Operator::OPERATOR_EQUAL_TO,
                           'ct.a'
                       ),
                   ),
                   Predicate\PredicateSet::TYPE_VALUE
               ),`

Comment: Are you joining CoolTable with CoolTable? If you joining using column 'a' and 'b' then only the matching values will be selected. So in the where clauses automatically you checking 'a' and 'b' columns for the matching values only.

Comment: Yes, I'm joining CoolTable with CoolTable. And yes, you are right. And I've resolved my answer by query redesign.